# Using Percents in Style Tag for Responsive Hover/Slide Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a picture that is in a 7:10 ratio (700px by 1000px). I want the top 50% of the image to appear on my website, but when hovered over the bottom portion slides up.  I got this to work with **normal pixels**, but I'm having trouble getting it to work **in percentages** for my responsive themed website. I have set the image to width=100%, and the image itself responds, but the container remains static. I think I need to make the container responsive but I'm not sure how to do this...

I tried width=100%, but it doesn't affect the css... I'm new at this so excuse me if this is something very basic... Thanks a lot!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title></title>

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<style>
.pictureContainer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pictureContainer img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
.pictureContainer img:hover {
    top: -500px;
}

.pictureContainer img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;

    transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}
.pictureContainer img:hover {
    top: -500px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="pictureContainer">
<a href="MyWebsiteLink">
<img src="MyImageLink" /></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i took your question to mean that half of the image is always visible.. and that it scales to always fill the width of the screen.

as such implementing something that will maintain a 70% height to width ratio requires a little help from the ideas that http://fluidsquares.com/ came up with (use `height:0` and an internal `padding-bottom` element with another internal `position:absolute` element to give you perfect scalable ratios)

i created a working jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Q58xL/1/